# BIRT: scripted datasource cannot access public methods

Tags: birt

I´m trying to set up a scripted Datasource using pojos from my app (java 1.8).
I embedded a reportengine (4.4.0) in my app via maven and created a report with a scripted datasourse. The pojos can be seen by the report.

```
bookSrv = Packages.de.me.service.ReportDataService;
```

works.

I can access static methods of my object, but whatever i try, accessing public methods or fields results in an exception.

So

```
books = bookSrv.books;
```

gives

org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java class "de.me.service.ReportDataService" has no public instance field or method named "books". (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="5"]/method[@name="open"]#11)
or

```
books = bookSrv.showMyBooks('Peter');
```

gives

org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java class "de.my.service.ReportDataService" has no public instance field or method named "showMyBooks". (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="5"]/method[@name="open"]#11)

But:

```
books = Packages.me.tdesk.service.ReportDataService.myBooksStatic('Peter');
```

works like expected. (Simply a static wrapper around my method)

here is my java class:

```
package de.me.service;

import de.me.model.dto.BookDto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReportDataService {

    public ReportDataService() {
        books = showMyBooks("Peter");
        System.out.println("ReportDataService.init()");
    }

    private List<BookDto> books;

    public List<BookDto> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(List<BookDto> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }



    public List<BookDto> showMyBooks(String commodity){
        BookDto dto = new BookDto(12l, "otto", "My", 12l);
        List<BookDto> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(dto);
        dto = new BookDto(122l, "paul", "My", 122l);
        books.add(dto);
        return books;
    }


    public static List<BookDto> myBooksStatic(String commodity){
        ReportDataService rep = new ReportDataService();
        return rep.showMyBooks(commodity);
    }
}
```

Many thanks
Uli

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

shouldn't it be

```
bookSrv = new Packages.de.me.service.ReportDataService(...);
```

instead of

```
bookSrv = Packages.de.me.service.ReportDataService;
```

?

With the second one, bookSrv will be the Java *class* ReportDataService (which is an object in Rhinoscript), not an *instance* of the class.

Comment: ... or, if your ReportDataService is a singleton, maybe bookSrv = Packages.de.me.service.ReportDataService.getInstance() ?